# Beginner on PyQt4 - No window icon

Tags: python, python-2.7, icons, pyqt, pyqt4

I can't figure out why there is absolutely no icon displayed on my window. The icon is on the same directory as the python script.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Icon_test')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('application-icon.png'))        

        self.show()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: For a relative path to work, it must be relative to the _current directory_, which is not necessarily the same as the directory the python script is in.

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the complete path to image file.

```
import sys
import os.path as osp
from PyQt4 import QtGui

#setting the path variable for icon
path = osp.join(osp.dirname(sys.modules[__name__].__file__), 'application-icon.png')

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Icon_test')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(path))        

        self.show()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`sys.modules[__name__].__file__` will give the current module path

Comment: You can shorten `sys.modules[__name__].__file__` to just `__file__` (yes, its a global defined for all modules before the code is actually executed).

Comment: "Complete path" could also be relative to where app is run from.